# Error Pivot Table syncfusion ej2-angular when I use minus operator - ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I have problems only when I use operator minus

```
  calculatedFieldSettings: [
    { name: 'Binaural', formula: '"Sum(the_order_count)" == "0" ? "0" : ("Sum(the_unit_count)" - "Sum(the_order_count)") / "Sum(the_order_count)" * "100"'},
    { name: 'Av', formula: '"Sum(the_order_count)" == "0" ? "0" : "Sum(the_order_value_net)" / "Sum(the_order_count)"'},
    { name: 'Avuni', formula: '"Sum(the_unit_count)" == "0" ? "0" : "Sum(the_order_value_net)" / "Sum(the_unit_count)"'},
  ]
```

return error 
core.js:6014 ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the reported issue at our end. But we are unable to reproduce the issue. Meanwhile, we have prepared a sample for your reference in angular platform. Please check the below sample link.

**Sample Link:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbpper-dziwb9?file=app.component.ts